Blazor WebApp with APIController and OIDC Authentication
does anyone have an example of a Blazor WebApp in combination with WebAPI APIController?
I would like to make my application accessible via Api. My own frontend should then also use the API.
The frontend is InteractiveAuto. So it is executed on the server first. Here I am always missing the cookie in HttpClient. If I add the cookie to the request, everything works as desired, but I don't know if this is the right solution.

Added ApiControllers
MapControllers
Add OIDC Authentication
Added Scoped HttpClient
HttpClient has no AuthCookie => Here is the problem


Hey and welcome at SO. Please try to share a bit of the code which you have created so fare.
